# xorg keyboard config not working (us altgr-intl no deadkeys)

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xinput, dead-keys

I'm trying to get my keyboard to use the us layout with variation altr-intl and no deadkeys.

Somehow my xorg-keyboard-config does not take effect. I looked up the config here [arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration) but there seems to be a mistake in my config which I was unable to find.

My current (not working) config looks like this:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf

# Written by systemd-localed(8), read by systemd-localed and Xorg. It's
# probably wise not to edit this file manually. Use localectl(1) to
# instruct systemd-localed to update it.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option "XkbVariant" "altgr-intl"
        Option "XkbOptions" "nodeadkeys"
EndSection
```

I get it to work by using the following command but as you might know this is not persistent:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option nodeadkeys
```

I don't want this command to end up in my xprofile file or such. I would prefere to do it in xorg as I did with my trackpad, mouse ect.

The keyboard I'm using is a keychron k2 connected by cable. Here is the output of xinput, in case the keyboard doesn't get identified correclty:

```
xinput list 

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3053-003                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Keytron Keychron K2                       id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Mouse                   id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keytron Keychron K2                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Keytron Keychron K2                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023       id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I tried to identify the keyboard by using "MatchIsProduct" "Keytron Keychron K2" without any luck either.

I'm running manjaro i3 community edition. The keyboard settings set in the manjaro-settings are also the wanted layout so I don't think that these settings would mess up my xorg config. I'm trying this on a thinkpad T550.

With the current config I get the us keyboard without deadkeys but the altgr-intl variant is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check other config files that changing the keyboard settings. e.g 70-keyboard.conf or anothers.
Or you can try rename the 00 to higher number.

I am not sure. That is my mind.

I think if X is starting succesfully config is not wrong. So it can be changed by another config.

Comment: Yes, xorg is starting normally. I got no other keyboard settings in xorg configured except for this one. I'm not sure what other settings could overwrite those. I will change the number of the file but I dont think that should make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

> /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf ... It's probably wise not to edit this file manually. Use localectl(1) to instruct systemd-localed to update it.

> Somehow my xorg-keyboard-config does not take effect.

There should be no more `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`,
instead **xorg will generate those X11-files**.

With **systemd** the keymap layout for the X11 server can be set using the `localectl` command. And see your **locale** with `localectl` command too.

- list all **X11 keyboard layouts** with `localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts`
- list all available **variables** `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants`
- list all available **options** `localectl list-x11-keymap-options`
- please take a look in this **manpages** `man localectl` too

**Example**:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap us altgr-intl terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```