# Setting an X11 keymap on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am running Arch Linux and I would like two input languages on my system.

1. English, UK
2. Kurmancî (Northern Kurdish)

In my `.xinitrc` I have the following:

```
# keyboard layout
setxkbmap -layout gb &
```

And that sorts out the `English, UK` for me. However, I am not sure how to add the Kurdish layout.

The layout I'm after is:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sy:    name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Syria, Latin Q)";
```

But I don't know what command to run to activate that layout.

In case it matters, I am using:

1. Linux Firmware version `20211027.1d00989-1`
2. bspwm as the window manager, coupled with polybar.

**UPDATE**

In my `sxhkdrc` file, I added the following:

```
# set x11 keyboard layout
alt + shift {e, k}
  {setxkbmap gb, setxkbmap -layout sy -variant ku}
```

And restarted my machine, now when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> the keyboard layout changes to Kurdish! **However**, if I run `localectl status` I still get:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF8
       VC Keymap: gb
      X11 Layout: n/a
```

Even though the layout is changed to Kurdish! I was expecting `X11 Layout: sy`

Answer (score 1):

- Use [sxhkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Sxhkd), develoved by bspwm devs. Write this in `~/sxhkd/sxhkdrc` and start sxhkd in autostart.

```
alt + shift {setxkbmap gb , setxkbmap ku}
```

- Alternately, use [iBus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IBus).

Comment: Thanks, sadly that doesn't seem to work? See updated question.

Comment: Where is your X11 layout ?

Comment: I had misunderstood how the `sxhkd` config worked. See update.

Comment: But, it works, right? Don't touch it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/674209/497217) for **systemd**, cause you used **localectl**.

Btw. you wont need `~/.xinitrc` to set locales in the case of your init-system.

Comment: hmm I tried `localectl set-x11-keymap sy ku` and it doesn't seem to have changed the layout.

Comment: locale **ku** doesn't exist on my system and I am not sure two locales simultaneously will work. try `localectl set-x11-keymap sy` only.